# for-free installation of php-mssql and dependencies

Tags: sql-server, php, redhat, odbc

*Problem*: trying to install RPMs for RedHat EL, php-mssql. There does not appear to be a free open-source option for connecting to MSFT SQL Server database.

Has anyone had any luck with this?

Comment: What on earth is with the downvotes to the question and the answers?

Comment: I don't know.. I just upvoted them. I just saw this happened on a few questions that don't deserve it.  I would speculate that it's a nefarious user...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not had any luck, although I did look at an ODBC/ODBC bridge. Note that this ODBC/ODBC bridge is not free for anything but a trial, but it seems very well supported.

http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/php/sql_server_unix_tutorial.html

Answer (score 2):

The Sybase/MSSQL bindings are part of [the core PHP distribution](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mssql.installation.php), you just need to build with the appropriate options.  They're regular open-source.